# jQuery Organization of document.ready logic

Tags: jquery, document-ready

Most jQuery enabled web applications I have worked on have organized document.ready logic in one of two ways.

1. A global document.ready is is used in a site wide JS file, and all document.ready logic is  enclosed in that execution block.
2. document.ready logic is explicitly added to specific pages that need them.

Typically, I go with option 1 so that the javascript will enjoy the benefits of javascript consolidation and minification that is easily applied to a standalone file vs a block of javascript on a page.

However, as a site grows, the amount of logic that needs to execute at document.ready also grows, and I suspect the amount of selectors being evaluated can affect the snappiness of the  site.

I've considered developing a framework for this whereby a global technique can be applied that uses either the URL or a root element attribute to determine which code should be executed on document.ready and cut down on the number of selectors being evaluated.

**EDIT: For More Clarification...**
In a simple example, I have 2 different pages.  On each of those pages, logic (including selectors) needs to execute on document.ready, but the logic, ideally, is only executed when those pages are loaded, not on every page for the entire site.

Does something like this already exist, or are selectors cheap enough in general that I shouldn't care?

Comment: Based on the URL?  like you execute some of the code sometimes, but not others?  Take a look at [Backbone with History](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)

Comment: I haven't used backbone, but based on the description at your link, I don't believe this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using something like you describe in my latest project. I've given the HTML tag in each page a unique ID and then I use that to initialize the code specific to that page:

```
$(function() {
    //for index.html (view/edit)
    if($("html#view").length>0){
        ReadView();
    }
    //for create.html (add)
    if($("html#create").length>0){
        CreateView();
    }
    globalFunction();
});

var ReadView = function(){
    ...
};

var CreateView = function(){
    ...
};

var globalFunction = function(){
    ...
};
```

Not only does this assist in keeping the JavaScript "snappy," as you put it, but it helps with name-spacing and helps prevent variable collisions. I also find that it helps when other programmers look at the code, to make sense of things in a more organized manner.

Answer (score 0):

1st off, i mainly work with single page applications.

This is how i usually operate:

```
// Main module
;(function($, win, undefined) {
    var module = {
        _currentPanel,
        initialize: function() {
            // all my global bindings here
        },

        // Only included to understand whats going on in the sub-module below
        displayPanel: function(panelName) {
            if (!!module._currentPanel) {
                $(module._currentPanel)
                    .hide(0)
                    .triggerHandler('hide.panel');
            }

            module._currentPanel = panelName;

            $(panelName)
                .show(0)
                .triggerHandler('show.panel');
        },          
    };

    $.extend("namespace", module);
})(jQuery, window);



// Sub modules
;(function($, win, undefined) {
    var module = {
        something: function() {
            // ..nothing to see here, this is just how i construct my modules
        }
    };


    // Event bindings specific to this module
    $('#geo-panel').bind('show.panel', function() {
        // wire up init() stuff   
    });
    $('#geo-panel').bind('hide.panel', function() {
        // wire up dispose() stuff
    }); 

    $.extend("namespace", module);
})(jQuery, window);
```

So whats going on there ?

My main module holds all the global stuff ..that was logical :) With a initialize() function that i call somewhere when i load the page. This hooks up all my generic bindings/selectors that are useful on all pages (or views in this case).

Then my sub-modules hold bindings to events that i trigger when i display the various pseudo-pages in my application. They all react to .triggerHandler() which i use quite a bit to be able to separate my logic throughout the site.

displayPanel("#geo-panel");

displayPanel("#someother-panel");

Both the main module & the sub-modules are then aggregate into a big js file. There's some redundant $.extend() going on here (i use it to create namespaces on the fly), and it allows me to split everything into specialized sub-module (preferences, profile, search, ..) that get automatically built/aggregated on application build.

However if i wasn't using a single page application, then  i would either:

1. just change all the references from `#panel-geo`, to something more like `#pageX #panel-geo`
2. or go for 1 common js for all pages, and 1 specific js for each page

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is to have two (could be more, though) sets of files. An app.js file that has things that are global to the site and a page.js file for each page that has things specific to that page.

The page.js file is set up with an object, the `myapp.page` object, that holds functions that are specific to that page but *also* relate to things that have a global context. This file also contains things that are specifc to that page and *do not* relate to anything global.

A typical page.js would look something like this:

```
var myapp = mayapp || {};
myapp.page = {
    onReady: function($, undefined) {
        // page specific initialization that will need to use
        // things initialized in the global initialization
    },

    // for other events that I want some page-specific behavior 
    // in addition to the global behavior. For example, onresize:
    onResize: function(e, anything) {
        // page specific response to some event
        // that uses or relies on things done in the global
        // onresize listener
    }
}

// stuff that is page specific that is completely autonomous.
// This could also be included in the myapp.page.onReady, if preferred.
// I like the seperation because it illustrates what on the page 
// depends on global resources.
$().ready(function() {
    $('#some-form').submit(function(e) {
        // the form only exists on this page so no need to put it in
        // the page.onReady callback function
    });
});
```

The app.js file uses $().ready(...) to do stuff on page load. It then calls the page specific JS:

```
$().ready(function() {

    var myapp = mayapp || {};

    // do global stuff first
    globalStuff();
    // then page specific
    if (myapp.page && typeof myapp.page.onReady === 'function') {
        myapp.page.onReady($);
    }

    // if there are some events that have both global page specific things
    // going on I would have something like this:
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
        // global behavior
        someResult = processedTheSameOnAllPges();

        // then page specific
        if (myapp.page && typeof myapp.page.onResize === 'function') {
            myapp.page.onResize(e, someResult);
        }
    });
})
```

I have things seperated this way mostly for simplification but it would definitely have a performance impact for large sites. This does have the down-side of being separate files, so there will be two downloads. But, every page is only be downloading and executing what it needs.

Regarding performance, if you're initialization is sluggish because of your selectors, maybe consider going native for some or all of them.

For specific data, with a particular focus on selectors (mentioned several times in the OP), the best I can offer are some interesting jsPerf cases:

- http://jsperf.com/native-vs-jquery-class-selectors/2
- http://jsperf.com/native-vs-jquery-selectors
- http://jsperf.com/js-native-vs-jquery-selector

A huge limitation of these tests, IMHO, is the 'preperation code' they use. These test scenarios are not realistic and, from what I've noticed, the DOM you're running your selectors on has a *huge* impact on their performance.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to organize you page could be to user jquery's triggerHandler to "split up" the *document.ready* event, like this:

on ready:

```
$(namespace.eventPool).triggerHandler("namespace.preready");
$(namespace.eventPool).triggerHandler("namespace.domready");
$(namespace.eventPool).triggerHandler("namespace.postready");
```

on loaded templates from ajax (example):

```
$(namespace.eventPool).triggerHandler("namespace.templates.loaded");
```

example useage in pseudo code:

```
function loadTemplates(){
    $.get...
    $(namespace.eventPool).triggerHandler("namespace.templates.loaded");
}

$(namespace.eventPool).on({
   "namespace.preready":loadTemplates,
   "namespace.templates.loaded":invalidateCache
});
```

etc.

The idea is to avoid just slamming everything off at once and have just a teeny tiny bit of event based pub/sub

Answer (score -1):

Each page "knows" which JS needs to be executed on that page. So define those functions in your .js files, and have a doc-ready call in the HTML markup to call only those functions.

While you should avoid placing significant JS code in your HTML, it would be perfectly acceptable to call an init function or two.

Comment: -1 I'm well aware of how to do this...as I stated in my question.  I'm looking for some concrete data on if this is even a valid concern AND if so, if there are existing libraries/plugins that help deal with this concern.

Comment: I'd say that if a HTML page gets to the point where you are starting to try to figure out how to load balance you selector executions, then it's probably time to start rewriting the app. Selector madness is much more likely to happen in jqueryui style apps where you are delegating all the styling to js functions, than in bootstrap style apps, where UI is mainly CSS based and then js enhanced.

Comment: Though as a partial answer I could say that selectors are as expensive as their complexity. A class selector will be more expensive than an id selector, as would a element or attribute selector. Another thing to take into account is context and caching.  Use .find() or pass a context to your jQuery() when possible. Personally I use a mix of global & page based events. I also often find myself using trigger() as an event bus to separate my logic.